# How to apply styles for empty lines in between the paragraph in tinymce, is it even supported in tinymce?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have been trying to findout on how to apply styles for emptylines in tinymce.
For Example:

newline1

newline2

When I select the above two lines and change the font, and when I try to type something in the empty line inbetween the two lines , newly applied style is not applying for the content in the emptyline.

Current Version I am using : 4.7.13

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE 4.x is no longer a supported release of TinyMCE.  If you try this same process in the latest release (5.10.x as I write this) you should get your intended behavior.

The key configuration option is `format_empty_lines`: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-formatting/#format_empty_lines

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    format_empty_lines: true,
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you Michael for clearing my query. Need one more assistance on empty_lines. In the source code plugin, we are unable to get the style elements for empty lines, it is getting removed in the getContent() function I think. Is there any way to allow style elements for empty lines by configuration or by modifying getContent() function of tinymce ?

Comment: I am asking this because I need to retain the style elements of empty lines over different pages. So is there any configuration for this or can I modify getContent() function in local to achieve this and want to know whether modifying will cause any regressions. Kindly check this query and comment so that I can proceed with your solution Michael.